# If I have got content of line 2 I want to get content of line 9. How to do?

Tags: python

I have text file:

```
[1]AAAAAA
[2]BBBBBB
[3]CCCCCC
[4]DDDDDD
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]111111
[9]2222222
[10]333333
[11]4444444
[12]555555
[13]6666666
```

If I have  got content of line 2 I want to get content of line 9. How to do?

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: Add the code for getting the content of line 2 so that we'll be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print [line.strip().split(']')[-1] for i,line in enumerate(f) if i in [1,8]]
```

*out:*

```
['BBBBBB', '2222222']
```

Answer (score 3):

Either read the entire file into memory as a list and index it directly.

```
with open("myfile") as data:
    lines = data.readlines()
lines[8] #9th line
```

Or count up to the line you want via iterating each line of the file like object.

```
with open("myfile") as data:
    for count, line in enumerate(data)
        if count == 8:
            print line
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
print open("file.txt", "r").readlines()[8]
```

Comment: This might not ensure the file closes